# Access MongoDB in Hadoop?

Tags: mongodb, hadoop

I combine the MongoDB into Hadoop by using MongoDB-Hadoop plugins.
( http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Hadoop+Quick+Start )

I found that PHP could access HBase by using Thrift. 
Is it possible to access ( read / write ) MongoDB by using PHP and Thrift, or any other solutions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to query MongoDB with PHP and an ODM, you should take a look on

Doctrine or Lithiums Data Mapper

- Doctrine: [Doctrine Info](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/index.html)
- Lithium: [Lithium PHP Library](https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium)

I am sure, that you could easily use lithium mappers to start hadoop jobs and querying hadoop.